# C# get pair closest to value

Tags: c#, list, numbers, closest

I have this scenario:

```
public class Pair
{
    public decimal Min { get; set; }
    public decimal Max { get; set; }
    
    public Pair(decimal min, decimal max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }
}

public List<Pair> MyPairList = new List<Pair>()
{
    new Pair(10, 15),
    new Pair(16, 20),
    new Pair(21, 30)
};
```

How can I get the pair closest to a value?

E.g:

- if the value is **5**, the pair returned should be the **first one** (because 5 is closest to the Min value of the first pair)
- if the value is **40**, the pair returned should be the **last one** (because 40 is the closest value to the Max value of the last pair)
- if the value is **18**, the pair returned should be the **second one** (because 18 is between the second pair)

Notes:

- a pair must not have Min/Max values from another pair (e.g.: (15,20) and (20, 25))
- a pair must not have its Min value lower than the Max value of its precedent pair. (e.g: (98, 105) and (102, 200))

Comment: If you don't need to worry about overlaps then just order on `x => value < x.Min ? x.Min - value : value > x.Max ? value - x.Max : 0` and take the first one.

Comment: A bit off topic, but your assigning min and max has a big problem, in that you are trusting the input. What if someone did `new Pair(15,5);`? You don't have error checks so now your min will in fact have the larger value and max the smaller value.

Comment: Please can you define your conditions properly? Your examples give a vague idea, but it's not what your criteria is. For example, why is the pair returned should be the first one if 'value' is 5? Is that because `Min` of first pair has the closest value to it? Or do we consider both `Min` and `Max` to make that decision? For example if there was another pair (-10,4) would that be considered 'closer'?

Comment: @Sach, yes 5 is closest to the Min value of the first pair. In case of  (-10,4) 5 would still be considered the closest (because 5 is close to 4, which is the max value of that pair)

Comment: I can check if Max < Min and throw an exception. This isn't an issue.

Comment: Still you haven't defined your criteria properly. Think of all possibilities. For instance, what if you had another like (20, 22) for instance? What's the choice in case of `value=18` then? Both 16 and 20 are two away from 18.

Comment: A pair must not have the min/max of another pair.

Comment: Well you should mention that in the post, and still that doesn't guarantee that a situation like that I mentioned. Consider your value is 100 and two pairs (98, 105) and (102, 200).

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: You need to encode all your rules in code (*a pair must not have Min/Max values from another pair* for example, but also that min must be < max).  Then write a `Distance` method that implements the distance you will be using for "Closest".  Once you have that, you just look for the minimum distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
    public static Pair FindClosest(IEnumerable<Pair> list, int value)
    {
        Pair closest = null;
        
        if (list != null && list.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var pair in list)
            {
                if (value <= pair.Max)
                {
                    closest = pair;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (closest == null)
            {
                closest = list.Last();
            }
        }
        
        return closest;
    }
```

Comment: This method has a significant drawback in that you depend on data to be correct for this method to work. You are using the value of `Min` indirectly by referring to `Max` and depending on user supplying a list of `Pair` objects that's error free, which I don't think is an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you don't take `Max` into account and the 'closeness' is based solely on `Min`. But before that, let's fix your class a bit. As it is now, you trust the assignment of minimum and maximum values to be correct, but I would add a small error fix there.

```
public class Pair
{
    public decimal Min { get; set; }
    public decimal Max { get; set; }

    public Pair(decimal min, decimal max)
    {
        if (min > max)
        {
            var temp = min;
            min = max;
            max = temp;
        }

        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }
}
```

Next, there's multiple ways of getting the 'closest' value. An approach I'd use is using `Aggregate()` function.

```
pairs.Aggregate((current, next) => Math.Abs(current.Min - value) < Math.Abs(next.Min - value) ? current : next);
```

But I must say that you still haven't defined the problem clearly. For instance, even considering your given rules, consider the following sequence of pairs.

```
var myPairList = new List<Pair>()
{
    new Pair(10, 15),
    new Pair(16, 19),
    new Pair(20, 23),
    new Pair(25, 30)
};
```

And consider a `value = 18`. The sequence above doesn't violate any of your rules, but there's two `Min` values that are equally close to `18`. Which one do you need to pick?

The solution I've given will pick `(20, 23)` pair since it goes through the entire list.

Essentially, your solution depends on how you define your criteria and you haven't done that yet.

Comment: If the value is 18 then it should pick (16, 19), because 18 is closer to the Max value of the 2nd pair than it is to the Min value of the 3rd pair. @Eddy's answer returns the right pair.

Comment: As I said form the beginning, you should _fully_ define the criteria for picking an element first, and _then_ post the question. You seem to be just adding criteria as we go along which isn't helpful.

The other answer has the serious drawback of depending on data being correct, which isn't a great idea when it comes to programming.

Comment: @Sach If you feel the question isn't in a state where it can be answered, then why did you post an answer to the question?